# T SQL Update rows using max function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery, max

With this query what I need SQL to do is update a column value based on another column so that it grabs the most recent MAX ID.

```
select 
    max(T1id), t1.v_code 
from 
    [Table1] T1
join 
    [Table2] t2 on t1.T1Code = t2.T2Code
where 
    t2.active = 0
    and t1.t1activesw = 0
    and t1.mapping not like '%selected%'
group by 
    t1.v_code
```

I'd like to join the select to the table on the version code id = max(t1.v_code) and then use the code as a sub select just not sure how to finish it.

Comment: Maybe it's too early in the morning for me, but I'm really having a hard time understanding what you want to do. Can you clarify the intent of the query?

Comment: T Clausen's post is correct in that I am trying for the results to get the highest t1.id for each t1.v_code.  The end goal is to update t1.active = 1 based on the highest ID for each t1.v_code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this, you get all data from the row for with the highest T1.id for each T1.v_code:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
      T1.*, 
      row_number() over (partition by T1.v_code order by T1.id desc) rn
  FROM
      [Table1] T1
  JOIN
    [Table2] t2 on t1.T1Code = t2.T2Code
  WHERE
    t2.active = 0
    and t1.t1activesw = 0
    and t1.mapping not like '%selected%'
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Edit: In order to update, replace(as requested in commment)

```
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

with

```
UPDATE CTE 
SET columnname = 'newvalue' 
WHERE rn = 1
```

this

Comment: Thanks t-clausen that's something I've not done before. Having only worked in existing control tables I've not set one up before!

Comment: Looking for how to update all of those records in the CTE.

Comment: You can update the CTE instead of selecting, changed my answer to show it

Comment: T Clausen that is indeed a solution which will get the desired results I was seeking. Marked as answer....Thanks